# update MongoDB collection it gives error: Command failed After applying the update, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to update a document in my web api, i write this code:

```
public Series Update(Series seriesIn)
{
    var name = seriesIn.Name; 
    var res = _series.FindOneAndReplace(series => series.Name == name, seriesIn);
}
```

but it gives me this error :

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command findAndModify failed: After applying the update, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id

Is there any way to fix it? or ignore _id when updating the document?

Comment: Remove the `_id` field from `seriesIn` before passing it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you (or your library/framework) are providing an _id in the upsert. If this is done the _id must [be the same as the existing _id on the document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#insert-a-new-document-if-no-match-exists-upsert).